# RDS Postgresql DB connection timeout from Heroku

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-rds, rds

I'm unable to connect to a new PostgreSQL in AWS RDS.

I have a Heroku app and I would like to use Amazon RDS for my database instead of Heroku. For that I've been following this guide: https://www.reinteractive.net/posts/128-heroku-app-backed-by-an-aws-rds-postgres-database

I've made a backup from my current Heroku DB and want to load it on the new database.

My security group for the database allows all inbound connections for port 5432 (0.0.0.0/0) and I've made a new VPC to have my DB set as Publicly Accesible (DNS hostnames and DNS resolution enabled). I created the database on postgres version 9.4.9.

However when I do:

```
    -f latest.sql --host=xxx.xxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=awsuser --password --dbname=mydatabase
```

from my computer, I only get a connection time out error:

```
    psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
            Is the server running on host xxx.xxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com" (1.2.3.4) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

The server is indeed running. In this case latest.sql is the backup I did. After this I edited the Database security groups to accept all connections (0.0.0.0/0) too.

[Database Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oYZJ.png)

(from what I've read this should not be necessary because I already have the VPC Security Group), but the result is the same.

Is there any way to trace what's going on / why is my connection getting blocked?

Comment: Is your instance set to _publicly accessible_?

Comment: RDS must sit on subnet which `Enable auto-assign Public IP` for public access.  If you put RDS inside VPC (put it nder VPC subnet), there is no database security group but VPC security group that you attach to the RDS.